# VB.NET : Grabbing and Tieing IP Addresses to Interfaces

Tags: vb.net, ip, ipv6, ipv4

I would like to find a way to grab the assigned IPv4 and IPv6 addresses to different interfaces and being able to determine which interface they're tied to.

Currently I am looping ' System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces ' and able to grab interface specific information:

```
        For Each nic As System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface In System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()

        myarr(count2, 0) = (String.Format("{0}", nic.Description))
        myarr(count2, 1) = (String.Format("{0}", nic.GetPhysicalAddress))
        myarr(count2, 2) = (String.Format("{0}", nic.OperationalStatus))
        myarr(count2, 3) = (String.Format("{0}", nic.Speed))

        count2 += 1


    Next
```

Through this method I can't determine a simple method to grab assigned IP Addresses unfortunately.

The most common method that I can easily find with google-foo is to find your IP via going through something like the following:

```
Dim ipAdd As IPAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.First(Function(f) f.AddressFamily = Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
```

Which is fine and dandy but I can't determine which interface is being used nor can it determine an assigned IP Address that's not going through DNS or mulitple NICS.

I can possibly do some ghetto method of issuing a command-line command and parsing all the information out of ipconfig or getting a GUID and running through the registry but I feel like there should be an easier more effecient method.

A good example of  what I want is the ability to produce a list like IPCONFIG where it has interface information and their designated IP Addresess, etc...

Answer (score 1):

in you for-loop try

```
Dim ip = nic.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses(0).Address;
```